# Eclipse showing No launcher Activity found

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest

This is my android Manifest.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="uk.co.halfninja.wallpaper.parallax">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper" />

    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon">


        <service
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".ParallaxWallpaper"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.service.wallpaper" android:resource="@xml/wallpaper" />
        </service>
        <activity
            android:label="@string/wallpaper_settings"
            android:name=".ParallaxWallpaperSettings"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:exported="true">
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Still Eclipse showing the result

```
 ParallaxWallpaper] No Launcher activity found!
 ParallaxWallpaper] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
 ParallaxWallpaper] Performing sync
 ParallaxWallpaper] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
```

Please let me Know where am i doing the mistake, and what would be the solution...???

Comment: Move Intent filter between activity tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `intent-filter` tag from `service` to `activity`

Comment: trying that from last 10 mins dont know why its not allowing

Answer (score 0):

These lines should be in Activity tag

```
 <application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <activity
        android:label="@string/wallpaper_settings"
        android:name=".ParallaxWallpaperSettings"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"           android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
     </activity>

    <service
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".ParallaxWallpaper"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">
    </service>

    <meta-data android:name="android.service.wallpaper" android:resource="@xml/wallpaper" />

 </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

make activity as launcher you have made service as launcher. like that

```
 <activity
        android:label="@string/wallpaper_settings"
        android:name=".ParallaxWallpaperSettings"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
        android:exported="true">
   <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```